# Display mouse position from graph on a map

Tags: openlayers-2, arcgis-server, javascript, web-mapping, graph

i need to develop a web application which shows a map, that displays a GPS Route.
So far I can do this using Openlayers or ArcGIS Server.

Now I want to add an interactive graph below the map. In this graph I want to display for example "Speed" and on mouse-over on the Graph the corresponding location in the map should be displayed.

Does anyone know an existing library or can give me recommendations on which architecture to use? Or do I need to programm this thing from the ground up on my own?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We had done something similar in Flex Using the ArcGIS FLEX API.

Since you are working in JavaScript, have a look at the [Rickshaw Library](http://code.shutterstock.com/rickshaw/). Especially this Sample:[Interactive Hover Details](http://code.shutterstock.com/rickshaw/examples/lines.html)

You need to store your data such that it has 4 variables for each point, such as:

1. Speed
2. Distance From Starting point (or maybe Time?)
3. X value of point (or longitude)
4. Y value of point (or Latitude)

Use the first two variables for drawing the graph. On the Mouse-hover of the graph, use the X&Y values to draw a marker on the map.

Comment: This looks very promising. Thanks for the hint, I will try it this way.